# Android - Cannot open database in internal storage

Tags: android, sqlite

I can't open the database in my app internal directory. I use this code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(appRootDir + "/dbname", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

When I run this code, I got this error(which gives me no hint):

```
03-09 14:14:44.893: E/SQLiteLog(9604): (14) cannot open file at line 30279 of [00bb9c9ce4]
03-09 14:14:44.893: E/SQLiteLog(9604): (14) os_unix.c:30279: (13) open(/data/data/fido.contacts.merge/databases/contacts2.db) - 
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604): Failed to open database '/data/data/fido.contacts.merge/databases/contacts2.db'.
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:213)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:197)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:812)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:797)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:702)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:677)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at fido.contacts.merge.RootManager.UnlockFacebookContacts(RootManager.java:121)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at fido.contacts.merge.ui.OptionsActivity$1.onClick(OptionsActivity.java:87)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4128)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17142)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
03-09 14:14:44.903: E/SQLiteDatabase(9604):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-09 14:14:44.903: W/System.err(9604): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:213)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:197)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:812)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:797)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:702)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:677)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at fido.contacts.merge.RootManager.UnlockFacebookContacts(RootManager.java:121)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at fido.contacts.merge.ui.OptionsActivity$1.onClick(OptionsActivity.java:87)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4128)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17142)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4787)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
03-09 14:14:44.913: W/System.err(9604):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

By the same code I can open the same database in external directory like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/dbname", null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

I've also tried open a db in internal dir like a file to avoid bad path or permissions problem. I succesfuly runned this code:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(new File(appRootDir), "dbname"));
```

So, I can open db in external directory, I can open db like a file in internal directory, but I can't open db in internal directrory like a db. Any ideas?

Comment: Likely the database doesn't exist. Consider using `SQLiteOpenHelper` that takes care of creating the correct path and database file for you.

Comment: Like I have wrote, I can succesfully open the database by FileOutputStream, which, as I know, excludes the posibility of wrong path.